# Meteor JS: Iron router on click button

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteorite

I have this code

```
Template.home.events 'click .buy': (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  ???
  return
```

After the user click the button (`buy`) I want it will go to a router path `/product`. What shall I add in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try :

```
Router.go('/yoururl');
```

[Relevant entry in the Iron router guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

In plain old JavaScript, appropriate syntax would be:

```
Template.home.events({ 
  'click .buy': function () {
   Router.go('/product');
});
```

Note that if the element being clicked is not an anchor or form submission, you won't really need to use

```
event.preventDefault();
```